# Add registry file (*.reg) to setup project

Tags: c#, registry, setup-project

I see how to update the registry manually, by right-clicking on the project, select View, then Registry, but I have alot of registry changes that I need to incorporate into my setup project, and I've already exported each of them to a *.reg file. I don't want to have to go through and add each of them for the setup project manually again.

How can I add my *.reg registry files into the setup project?

Comment: Right-click the "Registry on Target Machine" root node and click Import.  It will ask for a .reg file.

Comment: @HansPassant YOU ARE THE WINNER. Please add as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment, right-click the "Registry on Target Machine" root node and click Import. It will ask for a .reg file.  And will populate the tree with what it found in the .reg file.  Just repeat this if you have more than one .reg file.

The Setup project designer doesn't exactly have the most discoverable user interface.  It uses right-click context menus a lot and commands are scattered between context menus, regular menus and buttons.  So if you are looking for a feature that you think ought to be there then some wishful left and right-clicking on UI widgets can help you get lucky.  Spending ten Friday afternoon minutes clicking away is advisable.  Note that it was removed from VS2012 and won't come back, it is still available in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the project and add the file to your setup project. Have your application go through the .reg file on first run to make sure the registry is properly set up.

Comment: So after the application is installed, execute it once, check for the *.reg files, run them, and when they are done, delete the files...

What if those registry values are required to START the application?

Comment: You put the code that checks for the appropriate registry entries before any of the code that needs the registry entries. Also, I wouldn't delete the .reg file. Might come useful later as a "Back to Defaults" option. Of course, that depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

You may add or update your .reg files programatically. Let's say, for example, that you may want to merge a given `file.reg` to your registry:

```
Process _re = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s file.reg");
_re.WaitForExit();
```

(Just keep in mind that newer Windows versions use Unicode instead of ANSI when creating/consuming .reg files.)